# Fetch request from React to Express doesnt work. Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, python-requests, fetch

this is request from react in App.js:

```
var data = fetch("/hi")
.then((res) => {
  res.text();
})
.then((data) => {
  return data;
});
```

this is my express hanlding of request:

```
app.get("/hi", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello!");
});
```

I thought it should return the string to my data variable that i wanted to render on the react main page, but i get **Objects are not valid as a React child.** error. I am new to react and googled entire google and didnt get any info how to fix it for me as im new to react and express)))

PS: i use functional components

Comment: Can you show your component that is using the data?

Comment: I guess your api request returns a JSON object or something like that - not __text__

Comment: @O.o — JSON is text … and we can see the server-side code: It doesn't return JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> .then((res) => {
>   res.text();
> })
> ```

You are calling the `text()` method, but you haven't done anything with the return value (which is a promise). You need to return it so it is available in the next part of the promise chain.

```
.then((res) => {
  return res.text();
})
```

or

```
.then((res) => res.text())
```

Answer (score -1):

When you send with express, it sends an HTTP response object similar to this
for line

```
res.status(200).send({ message: 'api.user.register.success' });
```

You will get an object like this

```
{
  data: {message: "api.user.register.success"}
  status: 200
  statusText: "OK"
  headers: {content-length: "39", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
  config: {url: "http://localhost:3000/user/register", method: "post", data: "{"email":"test@test.asd","userName":"lordg","password":"asdasd1","passwordRepeat":"asdasd1 
  "}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
  request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: 
  XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
  __proto__: Object
}
```

You need to look for the data variable of the response object to access the "hello!" string !